# Is there an rxjs operator which emits the latest value on subscribe and continues to emit new values?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to build an rxjs operator which I'll call `latest`. Here's an example of a Karma test demonstrating usage:

```js
const root = new Subject<string>();
const inner = new Subject<number>();
const obj = { 'foo': inner };
const sut = root.pipe(latest(value => obj[value])); // latest operator applied
root.next('foo');
inner.next(42);
const spy = jasmine.createSpy();
sut.subscribe(spy);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(42);
```

Here are the actual requirements:

1. It is like `BehaviorSubject`: any future subscribers to `sut` will immediately be `next`ed with the most recently received valid value. Note that it must subscribe to the `root` observable when the operator is called and immediately begin caching values for a future catch-up subscriber, even before anyone has subscribed to `sut` yet.
2. It is like `switchMap`: when the `root` observable emits a new value, that value is converted (via the input factory function) to a new observable (which I'll call the "inner observable") whose values are monitored for the output.
3. It is like `share`: it needs to multicast and to continue to process new subscriptions even after an inner observable has errored or completed. In fact, when a new subscription occurs after the inner observable errors, this new subscriber needs to get the most recent valid value immediately as though no error had happened.
4. It needs to emit no values to any subscriber until an inner observable has emitted a value.
5. It needs to error and release all current subscribers when the inner observable errors.
6. It needs to error/complete and release all current **and future** subscribers when the `root` observable errors/completes respectively.

The below is my code for this.

```js
function latest<TIn, TOut>(factory: (input: TIn) => Observable<TOut>): OperatorFunction<TIn, TOut> {
  return (src: Observable<TIn>) => {
    const subscribers: Subscriber<TOut>[] = [];
    let hasValue = false;
    let latestValue: TOut = undefined;
    let outerSubscription: Subscription = null, innerSubscription: Subscription = null;
    let rootError: any, rootCompleted = false, rootErrorReceived = false;

    outerSubscription = src.subscribe((value: TIn) => {
      if (innerSubscription) {
        innerSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
      innerSubscription = factory(value).subscribe((innerValue: TOut) => {
        hasValue = true;
        latestValue = innerValue;
        subscribers.forEach(s => s.next(latestValue));
      }, error => {
        innerSubscription = null;
        subscribers.splice(0, subscribers.length).forEach(s => s.error(error));
      }, () => {
        innerSubscription = null;
      });
    }, error => {
      rootErrorReceived = true, rootError = error;
      subscribers.splice(0, subscribers.length).forEach(s => s.error(error));
      if (innerSubscription) {
        innerSubscription.unsubscribe();
        innerSubscription = null;
      }
    }, () => {
      rootCompleted = true, latestValue = undefined;
      if (innerSubscription) {
        innerSubscription.unsubscribe();
        innerSubscription = null;
      }
      subscribers.splice(0, subscribers.length).forEach(s => s.complete());
    });

    return new Observable<TOut>((subscriber: Subscriber<TOut>) => {
      if (rootCompleted) {
        subscriber.complete();
        return undefined;
      }
      if (rootErrorReceived) {
        subscriber.error(rootError);
        return undefined;
      }
      subscribers.push(subscriber);
      if (hasValue) {
        subscriber.next(latestValue);
      }
      return () => {
        const i = subscribers.indexOf(subscriber);
        if (i !== -1) {
          subscribers.splice(i, 1);
        }
      };
    });
  };
}
```

It works correctly according to all my requirements, but there simply *must* be a more rxjs way of doing this. I've tried several combinations of `share`, `switchMap`, `catchError`, `onErrorResumeNext`, `Subject`, `ConnectableObservable`, and `BehaviorSubject`, but I can't figure out the right one, especially with the need to subscribe immediately and handle future subscribers after error.

I'm on rxjs 6.6.2, but I can (probably) update if need be.

Comment: did you try `shareReplay(1)` ?

Comment: What about `skipUntil()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `switchMap` and `shareReplay` like this

```js
root.pipe(switchMap(value => obj[value]), shareReplay(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a combination or `skipUntil()` & `share()`

```
const heartbeat = timer(0, 1000);

const waiter = of('go').pipe(delay(5000));
    
const myHotObservable = heartbeat.pipe(skipUntil(waiter), share());

myHotObservable.subscribe(console.log);

setTimeout(() => {
  myHotObservable.subscribe((v) => console.log('2', v));
}, 5000);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gpa1ss?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the implementation below meets your requirements for this operator. Most operators and deal with subscribing and unsubscribing for you.

In this case, there's only one subscription you'll need to manage yourself. That's the one you create early to make the observable begin even before any downstream subscribers arrive.

In this example, you can manage that via finalize.

```ts
function latest<T, R>(
  project: (input: T) => Observable<R>
): OperatorFunction<T, R> {

  return source$ => {
    const target$ = source$.pipe(
      switchMap(v => project(v).pipe(
        catchError(_ => EMPTY)
      )),
      shareReplay(1)
    );

    const liveSub = target$.subscribe();
    return target$.pipe(
      finalize(() => liveSub.unsubscribe())
    );
  }

}
```